# CSS Layering an SVG graphic over images

Tags: css, html, svg

Playing around with z-index is not overlaying the object with class logo over the leftStrip

```
.leftStrip {
  z-index: 199;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
}
.logo  {
  z-index: 299;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

notwithstanding attempts at applying the class both to the div or the object itself.

```
   <div>
      <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/Logo.svg" class="logo">      </object>
    </div>
    <div class="leftStrip">
      <img alt=" " src="/images/leftStrip.png">
    </div>
```

Or am I missing some peculiarity regarding SVG objects?

Comment: This looks like it ought it work - can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Never used fiddle before.  Just launched it.  images are running off localhost...  http://jsfiddle.net/dvo4/P6R3X/

Comment: Have you tried removing the position and z-index element from leftstrip and making the logo's z-index 1? In other words, leftstrip just has the display inside of it.

Comment: Try using an img tag instead of an object tag- IE9+ and all other browsers will render .svg files as img src no problem.

Comment: BuddistBeast; the object disappears entirely that way...  chrisgonzalez; no change observed by going to an img tag...

Comment: BTW, img tag leads to the object NOT being rendered.